# Python dont see kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

i want create little progam with using kivi. But when i write kv code, it not working.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (700, 300)

def launchClicker(instance):
     print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
      pass

MainApp().run()
```

And kv file code:

```
<MainApp>
GridLayout:
    cols:2

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        rows:3

        Label:
            text: "Your Mom"
        Label:
            text: "Your Mom"
        Label:
            text: "Your Mom"
    Button:
        text: "Submit"
```

When i run project, it have nothing problem or error. But i see only window without lables and buttons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPclM.png)

Comment: The `kv` file must be named `main.kv`. Is that the case.

Comment: And you don't need the `<MainApp>:` line.

Answer (score 1):

Include This In Your Python Code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
```

Then In Your `MainApp` Class Include this:

```
BLD = Builder.load_file("Example.kv")
```

Then Modify Build():

```
def build():
    return BLD
```

so This Will Be Your Final Code:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (700, 300)

def launchClicker(instance):
     print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)

BLD = Builder.load_file("Example.py")

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
      return BLD
if __name__ == "__main__":
MainApp().run()
```

Please Tell Me If This Works.